# Is some type of repeated measures mixed model ANOVA right for this data?

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova

For this experiment, there are 4 treatments applied to plants in a field: warmed, control, control + insecticide, and warmed + insecticide. These 4 treatments were randomly assigned to 12 plots, so there are 4 plots per treatment. The data I'm working with now is primarily concerned with differences between warmed and control. Plant composition is collected periodically throughout the summer, and this data has been collected for the past 6 summers. Here's an example of what the data looks like:

| plot | state | species | insecticide | half_cover_date | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | warmed | Acmi | insects | 201 | 2015 |
| A2 | control | Soca | no_insects | 194 | 2016 |
| B3 | warmed | Rufl | no_insects | 181 | 2017 |
| D1 | control | Dagl | insects | 190 | 2018 |

I'm interested in determining if there's a difference in the half_cover_date between warmed and ambient treatments, both for each individual year and from the beginning to the end of the study (2015 vs. 2020).
Should I treat plot and species as random effects for a mixed-model, as plots were randomly assigned and there may be species-specific variation? I'm still a bit unsure how to treat insecticide, since I'm not interested in its effects for this test. I think this test could be done using a repeated-measures ANOVA, but I'm unsure since I'm new to stats. I've tried this in R:

```
mod <- lmer(half_cover_date ~ state + insecticide + (1|species) + (1|plot), data)
anova(mod)
```

This doesn't account for year, however. I'd really appreciate help figuring this out!

Using R version 4.0.2, Mac OS X 10.13.6

Comment: You probably just need to include `year` and a fixed effect and interact it with `state`